# How do I build a datagrid using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script + GUI API, How can I build a datagrid?

I am trying to build an object to show a range from spreadsheet into google site, with title columns, data, and clicking on the title columns, order the data.. and a scroll bar.

could you please let me know some pointer to build it?

Comment: have you tried implementing? if so could you post the code snippets, so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used google apps script but I would assume that the Google Visualization api will work for creating a datagrid for you.

[Google Charts / Google Visualization api](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)

Answer (score 0):

You have access to a subset of the Visualization services in Google Apps Script, which are provided as [Charts Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/). The behavior you've asked for is available in `Class TableChart`.

This is the example shown in the documentation for [`Class TableChartBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/table-chart-builder), which creates a simple TableChart.

```
function doGet() {
  // Get sample data from a spreadsheet.
  var dataSourceUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A1%3AF' +
      '&key=0Aq4s9w_HxMs7dHpfX05JdmVSb1FpT21sbXd4NVE3UEE&gid=4&headers=-1';

  var chartBuilder = Charts.newTableChart()
      .setDimensions(600, 500)
      .enablePaging(20)
      .setDataSourceUrl(dataSourceUrl);

  var chart = chartBuilder.build();
  return UiApp.createApplication().add(chart);
}
```

To use it in a google site, first publish the script as a web app. Then, in your site, edit the page that you want to embed the TableChart in, and add a Google Apps Script Gadget. Edit the gadget, and paste the URL of your published Apps Script. You can set other properties for the gadget as you like.

More details are provided in the [Building a Sites Application](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part1) tutorial, especially [Section 4](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part1?hl=en#section4) and [Section 5](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part1?hl=en#section5)